# How do you steal the Palladium in A Total War Saga: Troy?

Tags: achievements, troy-total-war

Playing as Ajax (Salamis) in Mythos mode, upon conquering Zeleia I got an event that said a priest was said running to "Mount Ida" and that I should follow him there. The event also mentioned a prophecy related to the Palladium, and there's an achievement called "Broken Prophecy" that asks you to "Win a battle for Troy after successfully Stealing the Palladium."

But how do you steal said Palladium? There's no quest for it, no marker anywhere on the map. Neither Heroes nor Agents get a special "Search" action and spies can't even do anything against the city of Troy anyway. I've read a few people talking about moving your faction leader to the Troy region, but it didn't do anything in my case. (tried ending the turn in the region as well just to be sure)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Someone mentioned this in a post: The event started with moving Ajax to Zeleia and then moving both Ajax and spy to Troy region. not sure if its working, maybe worth it to try

Comment: @Kerk Yes I tried that, it didn't work even after passing the turn. Right now what I'm wondering is whether being in Mythos mode is preventing the event from working properly for some reason. I'll need to see if I have a save close to the end (but before the Troy battle) from my Agamemnon campaign in Truth mode, or else just start a new Truth campaign with an Achaean leader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point I'm fairly confident that the issue is with Mythos mode. There is a known problem (seemingly unrelated to this one at first glance) where a faction leader's army can't use the "Pet Cerberus" action if he's attached to the army, but other commanders can - apparently doing the "Monster hunt" quest battle can mess up other quests later. Perhaps it's thus related?

I'm thinking this because I played a game as Diomedes in Historical mode (which obviously does not feature quest battles against legendary monsters), and on the next turn after conquering Zeleia I got this mission:
[image]

It's indeed pretty straightforward and upon moving my faction leader and my spy to Troy's region, it completed successfully and I got the Palladium as an ancillary. So it's clearly supposed to trigger as soon as you conquer Zeleia and you're not supposed to have to "guess" anything - if it doesn't trigger immediately, it probably means that it's bugged for your current campaign.